# How to put Kendo row index on Html tag Id

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a kendo grid to display certain entities. I have an object property in the model of a said entity called action. This action is defined by following kendo template:

template: `'# if(true) {# <i id="trashIcon" class="fa fa-trash" ng-click="delete(\'#:id#\')"></i>#}'`

Currently, every fa-trash icon id is set to "trashIcon." I need to be able to add an index to this trashIcon id every time the model is called to display a new entity on the grid. Similar to {{$index}} in angular for ng-repeats.

Thank you ahead

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following inside your template.

First (you should have this already)

```
$scope.yourDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(...)
```

And then

```
//you can use angular template features here
template: "<i id='trashIcon-{{yourDataSource.indexOf(dataItem) + 1}}'></i>"
```

I just tested it works with the pagination as well.
Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/uumh4m1L/134/).

Comment: I tried and it only displays 1 after trashIcon. i'm using same datasource "data" that has all the properties of the entity. is dataItem a kendo keyword?

 e.g. "data.status" returns some value.. so i tried from your example:
{{data.indexOf(dataItem) + 1}} ?

Comment: @Giolla, you might be missing 'new kendo.data.DataSource' and using an object as data source. I edited the answer and linked a working example.
Yes dataItem is how you refer the data object of the current row in the template. It's a kendo-defined variable.